# Changing/Convert from UE4 coordinates to OpenGL coorinates

Tags: opengl, matrix, coordinates, matrix-multiplication, unreal-engine4

I am trying to convert from UE4 coordinates (Z up) to opengl coorinates (Y up) but I cant seem to get around it.

I do this Matrix transforming from `X+ right, Y+ up, Z- deep` to `Y+ right, Z+ up, X+ deep`
[mat = M]

```
 0  1  0  0
 0  0  1  0
-1  0  0  0
 0  0  0  1
```

But I end up getting the wrong result and also the rotation....

I get ActorTranfrom from (T) = this->GetTransform()

then
FTransform R = T * M

Then I do the R - ToMatrixWithScale() - then get send it to OpenGL backend.

But the orientation is wrong... What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "OpenGL coordinates". YOu set up whatever coordinate systems you like by using the appropriate matrices.

Comment: I am trying to do this -- X+ right, Y+ up, Z- deep to Y+ right, Z+ up, X+ deep